# Why doesn't the function draw the point?

Tags: java, graphics, mouse, draw, point

I am trying to draw a point on the frame whenever i click the mouse on it on the same position of the click.
The code I wrote/copied call the drawing function but the point isn't drawed and I can't figure out the problem. Here it's the code:

```
import static com.sun.java.accessibility.util.AWTEventMonitor.addMouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class MyCanvas
{
    JLabel view;
    BufferedImage surface;

    public MyCanvas()
    {
        surface = new BufferedImage(600,400,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        view = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(surface));
        Graphics g = surface.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.fillRect(0,0,600,400);
        //g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        //g.drawLine(10, 20, 350, 380);
        g.dispose();

        /*
        // RANDOM POINTS WORKING
        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                int x = random.nextInt(600);
                int y = random.nextInt(400);
                addNewElement(x,y);
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(200, listener);
        timer.start();
        */
    }

    public void addNewElement(int x,int y) {
        Graphics g = surface.getGraphics();
        drawNode(x,y,g);
        g.dispose();
        view.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyCanvas canvas = new MyCanvas();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        int vertexes = 0;
        // Change this next part later to be dynamic.
        vertexes = 10;
        int canvasSize = vertexes * vertexes;
        frame.setSize(canvasSize, canvasSize);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(canvas.view);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                //Restituisco le coordinate del click(x,y)
                System.out.println(e.getPoint());
                //NOT WORKING
                MyCanvas a = new MyCanvas(); 
                a.addNewElement(e.getPoint().x,e.getPoint().y);
            }
        });
    }

    public void drawNode(int x, int y, Graphics g)
    {
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 8, 8);
            g.drawOval(x, y, 8, 8);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you are creating a completely **new** canvas `a` on mouse clicks; and then you don't do anything with that canvas. What do you expect to happen from that? Hint: consider manipulating that `canvas` instance instead ...

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
  g.dispose();
  view.repaint();
```

Never dispose a GUI object you don't create. Also, `repaint()` will remove your point after drawing it, as it calls `paint()` that refreshes the image. Your point is not refreshed, as it is not included in `paint`. Also, note that you define the mouse event on the frame, and you apply the coordinates on the `view`.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem persist

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just figgured out the problem: I was instantiating a new class at every click. To solve it I just changed

```
MyCanvas a = new MyCanvas(); 
a.addNewElement(e.getPoint().x,e.getPoint().y);
```

to

```
canvas.addNewElement(e.getPoint().x,e.getPoint().y);
```